# Is there a phone emulator or something along those lines that can recieve SMS texts?

Tags: emulator, phone, authentication, validation

If there is an application that needs a phone number to validate, and you don't want to give them your actual number, is there a good software solution around this? Personally I prefer not to give any legitimate PII when its avoidable; wondering if there is a solid free work-around to this out there. Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you going to receive SMS without a phone number?